# Handling previous and successive records within a collection relative to an item in the view of the collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A collection is defined in a view, where links for each element's successive and previous items need to be generated. (a css-only lightbox.  While the index of those items is accessible,

```
<% @gallery.each_with_index do |article_gallery, index| %>
  <%= succ = @gallery[index + 1] %><%= succ.inspect %>
  <%= prev = @gallery[index - 1] %>
<% end %>
```

The inspection of the object returns the expected object

```
#<ArticleGallery id: 1, article_id: 16, image: "Screen_Shot_2022-11-17_at_07.46.05.png", position: 2, [...]>
```

But it's id cannot be accessed.  if `succ.id` in lieu of `succ.inspect` is called it is deemed to now be a nil object.

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

@output_buffer.safe_append='      '.freeze;@output_buffer.append=( succ = @gallery[index + 1] );@output_buffer.append=( succ.id );@output_buffer.safe_append='
```

What is the proper way to access an attribute for the relative previous or successive object?

Comment: Its unclear what you actually mean here and this code has no nil checking so you're bound to get nils at the beginning and end of the collection.

Comment: the goal is to get the id of the previous/successive element in the collection.  the index, via +1 / -1 allows to lopp through the collection (i.e. no nil).  Thus using the index, trying to get the object's id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Voltan is a partial answer, where it creates a useful array, but as the docs state, the return is `nil` & that is failing the requirement.

But that was a bit of a lead-in ot the actual solution. The solution was around, [but buried a bit deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444898/return-iterating-object-and-index-while-iterating/5445257#5445257) using ruby's `zip` method on array.

Given that the impact is on the view, we show the `prev` and `succ` id OR (to make the loop continuous) return the last or first element of the array in case the calculated index returns nil

```
<% @gallery.zip((0 .. (@gallery.size - 1)).to_a).each do |a, i| %>

  <%= a.image_url %>
  <% prev = @gallery[i-1] %> 
  <% if prev.nil? %>
    <%= @gallery[-1].id %>
  <% else %>
    <%= prev.id %>
  <% end %>

  <% succ = @gallery[i+1] %> 
  <% if succ.nil? %>
    <%= @gallery[0].id %>
  <% else %>
    <%= succ.id %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the last iteration @gallery[index + 1] will return nil
Try to use https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons instead of each_with_index

It will be smth like:

```rb
<% @gallery.each_cons(2) do |article_gallery| %>
  <%= succ = article_gallery[1] %>
  <%= prev = article_gallery[0] %>
<% end %>
```